# Why Does my JQuery Script Crash My Page?

Tags: jquery

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/WA4eD/4/

**JQuery:**

```
$('h3').each(function() {
    var colors = [],
        availColors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet'],
        randomColor;
    $('span', this).each(function() {
        do {
            randomColor = availColors[Math.floor(Math.random()*availColors.length)];
        }
        while ($.inArray(randomColor, colors) != -1)

        colors.push(randomColor);

        $(this).css('color', randomColor);
    });
});
```

This script you see is what I am trying to implement into my website, however all attempts I have made to implement have failed.

View Source: view-source:http://rafflebananza.com/new-website/index.html

Where the script currently is on my page is not the only place I have tried implementing, however all has resulted in the same result.

Feel free to use my script, what it does is if you have a bunch of h3 tags and the characters inside are in span classes, it will randomize the colour, different outcome on page load.

Comment: we can't see your page as it does not load anything, not even the html (this tells us that your script is not in a **DOM ready** script), so we need to go by parts, first, let's check if you're processing what you really need: wrap a `<div class="colorful-header">` around those `<h3>` and instead of `$("h3").each(...` use `$(".colorful-header h3").each(...` just to make sure you are doing all that in the right scope.

Comment: If you have more spans than the number of colors your `do while` loop will continue to run and `$.inArray(randomColor, colors) != 1` will not occur.  Also I would create your `availColor` array outside of the `$('h3').each()` so you're not creating every time it is called.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the explanation, it is becoming more and more clear to me.

Comment: and by the way, why do you need the `while` loop? - http://jsfiddle.net/WA4eD/9/

Comment: Your JSFiddle, now updated on my site, can pull up two colours next to one and other unlike my JSFille in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove the do while loop, as mentioned in the comments.

[Here is your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WA4eD/10/) with one way to do this

```
var defaultColors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet'],
    availColors = [],
    randomColor = '';

$('h3 span').each(function() 
{
        if(availColors.length == 0)
            availColors = defaultColors.slice(0);

        randomColor = availColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * availColors.length)];
        availColors = $.grep(availColors, function(value) 
                        {
                              return value != randomColor;
                        });
        $(this).css('color', randomColor);
});
```

Comment: This works brilliantly! Thank you very much @Kevin I am very grateful for your time spent to resolve my problems :)

Comment: I forgot to mention, because this is a new account I do not have the rating to +1, but when I do I'll come back to +1 your answer for your help.

Comment: Just to note, got enough rep to +1 and I've just done so :) @Kevin

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access an out of bound array index in the random color generator while multiplying the generated random number by array length. So if the random generator returns any value greater than  .9, you are multiplying it by array.length and thus trying to access an array element that does not exist. I believe that is causing the crush.

Fix  the following line by using a range from 0 to array.length.

```
 randomColor = availColors[Math.floor(Math.random()*availColors.length)];
```

You can specify a min and max value to get a random array index within the bound.

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Also, in your case it is possible that the do while loop will run forever as the exit condition in while loop might not happen for the same reason I described above.

Simplest change you can make is

```
randomColor = availColors[Math.floor(Math.random()*(availColors.length-1))];
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure where to implement your suggested modifications, could you please let me know?

Comment: You would put the `getRandomInt()` somewhere outside of the `$('h3').each()` then call it as such `randomColor = availColors[getRandomInt(0, availColors.length)];`

Comment: I am grateful for your help. I did not see your edits before I updated using Kevin's answer which works, I did try before your edits which did not seem to work.

Comment: I forgot to mention, because this is a new account I do not have the rating to +1, but when I do I'll come back to +1 your answer for your help.

Comment: Just to note, got enough rep to +1 and I've just done so :) @ZabedAkbar